# Importance and usage of being in relative clause

Tags: gerund-clauses

> An underflow is the result of larger negative exponents not **being**
>   available to represent the number.

What's the importance of usage of being here? Why is it used like that? What if I drop it from the sentence? Does meaning of the sentence change?

Comment: I wouldn't say that the "larger ..." clause acts as a noun, but that is simply a non-finite clause as **complement** of the preposition "of". The whole expression following "is" functions as predicative complement of "be" in its ascriptive sense. I agree with the rest of Stoney's answer, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Being* is essential here. This is not a relative clause but a 'gerund' clause--that is to say, a clause acting as a 'noun' and headed by a verb in the *-ing* form. The clause "larger ... number" must act as a noun because it is the object of the preposition *of*.

The main clause of the sentence is

> An underflow is the result of *X*.

*X* here, the cause of the underflow, is the proposition that

> Larger negative exponents are not available to represent the number.

But in order for this proposition to be employed as the object of a preposition the verb in finite form, *are*, must be recast as a non-finite 'gerund', the *-ing* form of the verb.

> **of** larger negative exponents not **being** available to represent the number.

*Not* is often, perhaps usually, moved in front of a gerund it negates.

Comment: +1 Nice explanation.

Comment: What is the difference from the sentence *An underflow is the result of larger negative exponents which are not available to represent the number.*

Comment: and this sentence, *An underflow is the result of not being larger negative exponents (which are) available to represent the number.*